# python not running in powershell ISE

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

when I type 'python' in either Windows powershell or the Command module (Windows 10), I get into the python environment. However, when I try the same in Windows Powershell ISE, I get an error message as per below. Any guidance as to what to do?

```
python : Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
At line:1 char:1
+ python
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Python 3.9.0 (t...MD64)] on win32:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: You can try ```python3```

Comment: Interactive console applications are not supported in ISE. Try to type just `powershell.exe` in it, and you should get an error message indicating it's not supported; same issue with other interactive console applications, just that it's not a part of the `$psUnsupportedConsoleApplications` (*which you can type into the ISE console*) list. Would suggest to use VSC for future use.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot run python interactively from Powershell ISE. Not only python you won't be able to run any interactive console apps.

In order to use python, you need to use `start python`, which opens up python cmdline in a new window.